# Audio issue – can't properly regulate the volume with usb speakers

Tags: usb, audio

**The context**:
I had this issue for a long time, since I use Debian, but I didn't quite realize it. I couldn't change the volume as I wanted to via the gnome interface (or via any interface, really), the only solution to get what I wanted was to change volume directly inside the application.
Only when I tried to connect a jack speaker I realized there was an issue (and it was not just poor design).

**The problem**:
When I have a usb speaker (which means, most of the time at my work station), the sound is overall too loud, like if it was at 90%-100% of a range of volume I would find acceptable. When I try to lower it, it only has an anecdotal effect, until I reach about 10%. There, the sound suddenly drops, and at 8% there is no more sound (I've tried with alsamixer to change the volume percentage-point per percentage-point). As I said earlier, with a jack speaker, the behavior is normal, what one would expect.

**My attemps**:
I've looked up of stack exchange, and on google, the only thing I found was [this article](https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/), but at the very first step my untouched configuration file doesn't correspond to what they say I should see (specifically, there is no `Element PCM` section), so I didn't go further, afraid of being unable to apply an other solution once I've f*d up my config files (which already happened to me).

**The request**:
Beside the obvious “*can you solve my problem thanks*”, I'd like some explanation on the advises (not only “*do these commands, change this file, and it'll be alright*”) in the case I'd like to change once more my configuration files without breaking the patch.

**Specs**:
I'm using **Debian 10** Buster, with **Gnome**. On my computer are installed **alsa** and **pulseaudio** (and maybe others which I don't know participate in the audio handling).

**Disclaimer**:
I didn't include any configuration file because I don't really know which to include, and god knows all the program that are involved in audio mixing/low-level interface/etc. have quite a big number of config files, but if any thinks it could be useful please specify which files do you want (or range of files).

Thanks for taking the time to read all of this.

Comment: Please post `uname -r`

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov 4.19.0-9-amd64

Comment: I don't how this can be done in Debian but please try installing something fresher and see if it helps, e.g. kernel 5.7.7. Kernel 4.19 was released ages ago and probably newer kernels handle audio USB devices better.

Comment: The kernel 4.19.* is the latest supported by Debian, installing a fresher one would mean "bypass" the actual packaging system... I am unsure about how much I want to do that. Are you sure this is necessary to solve this problem? (if it is I'll still try it)

Comment: There's no harm in installing "unsupported" kernels in any Linux distro as long as you don't break your packaging manager (DPKG/apt in your case) and don't break your filesystem (e.g. by modifying files again belonging to your packaging manager). Please install a fresh kernel and see if it helps. Again, kernel 4.19 is extremely old.

Comment: I tried to install a new kernel version, and I've ran into an outstanding number of problems (including but not limited to: no space left on my HD, kernel not working, me reinstalling my distro but having forgotten my bios password ­– don't laugh –, compilation errors). Btw, even if 4.19 is old, it doesn't mean it isn't reliable. Even if I agree on having a fresh kernel could patch the bug, I really think a "local" patch could also do the work, and due to "technical" difficulties, I would really enjoy such a local patch. Are you sure there is no such one?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I finally achieved installing kernel 5.4, and it now works perfectly!